# How to implement a lightweight long-lived thread based on a generator or asynchronous function in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to implement a user interaction script in the form of a lightweight, long-lived thread written in Rust. Inside the script, I have points where I asynchronously await user input.

In JavaScript, I would use a generator, inside which you can pass a question, and get back an answer, for example:

```javascript
function* my_scenario() {
    yield "What is your name?";
    let my_name = yield "How are you feeling?";
    let my_mood = yield "";
    ...
}

let my_session = my_scenario();
...
my_session.next("Peter");
my_session.next("happy");
```

However, Rust's generator method `resume()` contains no parameters! I cannot clone a generator or return it from a function in order to have many user sessions with different states. Instead of a generator, I thought of using an `async fn()`, but I do not understand how to call it at each step, passing the value there.

Comment: I don't understand why a generator should be able to receive argument. For me it should just generate the next value. What is the point to use a generator for this case ?

Comment: In other languages ​​it is possible, but how to act correctly in rust? I have my own event loop, and I just want to transfer control inside the asynchronous function when I get the value from the user.

Comment: Neither generators nor async functions will do what you want. Rethink your approach from the start.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, well, async functions kind of would. If you create an async function for getting next user response, you can then write an async function to manage the session, calling the async response getter—but you'll have to write the response getter using the fundamental tools of your chosen reactor, because that's how the actual waiting happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value from `yield` is effectively just another generator that has been implicitly passed to the first generator, except that it forces the two to be tied together in weird ways.

You can see that in your original code by the junk `yield ""` that you need in order to get a value even though you don't have anything to return. Additionally, your example requires that the user of the generator *know the answer to the question before it is asked*, which seems very unorthodox.

Explicitly pass in a second generator:

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::{
    io,
    ops::{Generator, GeneratorState},
};

fn user_input() -> impl Generator<Yield = String> {
    || {
        let input = io::stdin();
        loop {
            let mut line = String::new();
            input.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
            yield line;
        }
    }
}

fn my_scenario(
    input: impl Generator<Yield = String>,
) -> impl Generator<Yield = &'static str, Return = String> {
    || {
        let mut input = Box::pin(input);

        yield "What is your name?";
        let my_name = match input.as_mut().resume(()) {
            GeneratorState::Yielded(v) => v,
            GeneratorState::Complete(_) => panic!("input did not return a value"),
        };

        yield "How are you feeling?";
        let my_mood = match input.as_mut().resume(()) {
            GeneratorState::Yielded(v) => v,
            GeneratorState::Complete(_) => panic!("input did not return a value"),
        };

        format!("{} is {}", my_name.trim(), my_mood.trim())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_session = my_scenario(user_input());
    let mut my_session = Box::pin(my_session);

    loop {
        match my_session.as_mut().resume(()) {
            GeneratorState::Yielded(prompt) => {
                println!("{}", prompt);
            }
            GeneratorState::Complete(v) => {
                println!("{}", v);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ cargo run
What is your name?
Shep
How are you feeling?
OK
Shep is OK
```

You can provide hard-coded data as well:

```
let user_input = || {
    yield "Peter".to_string();
    yield "happy".to_string();
};

let my_session = my_scenario(user_input);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you strongly promoted me in understanding Rust!

Answer (score 0):

As of approximately Rust nightly [2020-02-08](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/68524), Rust's generators now accept an argument to `resume`, more closely matching the original JavaScript example:

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::{
    io::{self, BufRead},
    ops::{Generator, GeneratorState},
};

fn my_scenario() -> impl Generator<String, Yield = &'static str, Return = String> {
    |_arg: String| {
        let my_name = yield "What is your name?";
        let my_mood = yield "How are you feeling?";

        format!("{} is {}", my_name.trim(), my_mood.trim())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_session = my_scenario();
    let mut my_session = Box::pin(my_session);

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut lines = stdin.lock().lines();

    let mut line = String::new();

    loop {
        match my_session.as_mut().resume(line) {
            GeneratorState::Yielded(prompt) => {
                println!("{}", prompt);
            }
            GeneratorState::Complete(v) => {
                println!("{}", v);
                break;
            }
        }

        line = lines.next().expect("User input ended").expect("User input malformed");
    }
}
```