# How can I transfer some values ​into a Rust generator at each step?

Tags: rust, generator

I use generators as long-lived asynchronous threads (see
[How to implement a lightweight long-lived thread based on a generator or asynchronous function in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415904/how-to-implement-a-lightweight-long-lived-thread-based-on-a-generator-or-asynchr)) in a user interaction scenario. I need to pass user input into the generator at each step. I think I can do it with a `RefCell`, but it is not clear how to transfer the reference to the `RefCell` inside the generator when creating its instance?

```rust
fn user_scenario() -> impl Generator<Yield = String, Return = String> {
    || {
        yield format!("what is your name?");
        yield format!("{}, how are you feeling?", "anon");
        return format!("{}, bye !", "anon");
    }
}
```

The `UserData` structure contains user input, the second structure contains a user session consisting of `UserData` and the generator instance. Sessions are collected in a `HashMap`.

```rust
struct UserData {
    sid: String,
    msg_in: String,
    msg_out: String,
}

struct UserSession {
    udata_cell: RefCell<UserData>,
    scenario: Pin<Box<dyn Generator<Yield = String, Return = String>>>,
}

type UserSessions = HashMap<String, UserSession>;

let mut sessions: UserSessions = HashMap::new();
```

`UserData` is created at the time of receiving user input - at this moment I need to send a link to `UserData` inside the generator, wrapping it in `RefCell`, but I don’t know how to do it since the generator has a `'static` lifetime, and the `RefCell` lives less!

```rust
let mut udata: UserData = read_udata(&mut stream);
let mut session: UserSession;

if udata.sid == "" { //new session
    let sid = rnd.gen::<u64>().to_string();
    udata.sid = sid.clone();
    sessions.insert(
        sid.clone(),
        UserSession {
            udata_cell: RefCell::new(udata),
            scenario: Box::pin(user_scenario())
        }
    );
    session = sessions.get_mut(&sid).unwrap();
}
```

The [full code is here](https://github.com/epishman/habr_samples/blob/fcd4a1f9c943c8d274d88bf5ce686dce00b9e56a/chatbot/main.rs), but the generator here does not see user input.

Comment: If you're trying to access data between threads, you should be using some form of `Mutex` instead of `RefCell`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, Thanks, but the current program is single-threaded, the problem as far as I understood is that the generator has a 'static lifetime, and my RefCell(...) live less, and I still do not understand how to synchronize lifetimes.

Comment: `long-lived asynchronous threads` can you clarify this then?

Comment: Perhaps put it badly, I mean the analogue of gorutin only on generators or async / await. Gorutin takes up to 8Kb under the stack, which is sensitive, asynchronous is more economical. The problem is that in Rust these are nightly builds and weak documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: resumption arguments are a planned extension for generators, so at some point in the future it will be possible to resume the argument with `&UserData`.*

---

For now, I will recommend sharing ownership. The cost is fairly minor (one memory allocation, one indirection) and will save you a lot of troubles:

```
struct UserSession {
    user_data: Rc<RefCell<UserData>>,
    scenario: ..,
}
```

Which is built with:

```
let user_data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(udata));
UserSession {
    user_data: user_data.clone(),
    scenario: Box::pin(user_scenario(user_data))
}
```

Then, both the session and the generator have access to the `UserData` each on their turn, and everything is fine.

There is one little wrinkle: be careful of scopes. If you keep a `.borrow()` alive across a `yield` point, which is possible, then you will have a run-time error when trying to write to it outside the generator.

---

A more involved solution would be using a queue of messages; which would also involve memory allocation, etc... I would consider your `UserData` structure to be a degenerate form of a pair of queues: it's two queues with capacity for one message. You could make it more explicit with a regular queue, but that would not buy you much.

Comment: *a planned extension for generators* — can you link something for this so we can read up on it?

Comment: How to get a link to the data from the generator code, because in Rust there are no global variables or singletons. The only way is to pass the cell reference when the generator is initialized: 
`Box::pin(user_scenario(&some_ref))`
But the compiler prohibits this, since the lifetime of the generator is 'static, and any variable lives less (in our case, until we remove session from the HashMap).

Comment: @epishman: don't pass a link, pass a clone of the `Rc` :) I updated the answer to show how to.

Comment: @Matthieu M. Thank you very much for notes about `borrow()`, without you I would be stuck for a couple of days :)